# Adding column of weights to pandas DF by a condition on the DFs column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Whats the most pythonic way to add a column (of weights) to an existing Pandas DataFrame `"df"` by a condition on `dfs` column?

Small example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1, 2, 3], 'B' : [4, 5, 6]})
df
Out[110]: 
   A  B
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

I'd Like to add a "weight" column where if `df['B'] >= 6` then `df['weight'] = 20`, else, `df['weight'] = 1`

So my output will be:

```
   A  B  weight
0  1  4       1
1  2  5       1
2  3  6      20
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Here's one with type-conversion and scaling -

```
df['weight'] = (df['B'] >= 6)*19+1
```

**Approach #2**

Another possibly faster one with using the underlying array data -

```
df['weight'] = (df['B'].values >= 6)*19+1
```

**Approach #3**

Leverage multi-cores with [`numexpr` module](http://numexpr.readthedocs.io/projects/NumExpr3/en/latest/user_guide.html) -

```
import numexpr as ne

val = df['B'].values
df['weight'] = ne.evaluate('(val >= 6)*19+1')
```

Timings on `500k` rows [`as commented by OP`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49977723/adding-column-of-weights-to-pandas-df-by-a-condition-on-the-dfs-column#comment86972110_49977762) for a random data in range `[0,9)` for the vectorized methods posted thus far -

```
In [149]: np.random.seed(0)
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'B' : np.random.randint(0,9,(500000))})

# @jpp's soln
In [150]: %timeit df['weight1'] = np.where(df['B'] >= 6, 20, 1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.57 ms per loop

# @jpp's soln with array data
In [151]: %timeit df['weight2'] = np.where(df['B'].values >= 6, 20, 1)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.27 ms per loop

In [154]: %timeit df['weight3'] = (df['B'] >= 6)*19+1
100 loops, best of 3: 2.73 ms per loop

In [155]: %timeit df['weight4'] = (df['B'].values >= 6)*19+1
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.76 ms per loop

In [156]: %%timeit
     ...: val = df['B'].values
     ...: df['weight5'] = ne.evaluate('(val >= 6)*19+1')
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.14 ms per loop
```

One last one ...

With the output being `1` or `20`, we could safely use lower precision : `uint8` for a turbo speedup over already discussed ones, like so -

```
In [208]: %timeit df['weight6'] = (df['B'].values >= 6)*np.uint8(19)+1
1000 loops, best of 3: 428 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `numpy.where` for a vectorised solution:

```
df['weight'] = np.where(df['B'] >= 6, 20, 1)
```

Result:

```
   A  B  weight
0  1  4       1
1  2  5       1
2  3  6      20
```

Comment: Very good. Also time taken was really low: `Took 0.00399994850159` seconds for approximately 500K rows.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method using df.apply

```
df['weight'] = df.apply(lambda row: 20 if row['B'] >= 6 else 1, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
   A  B  weight
0  1  4       1
1  2  5       1
2  3  6      20
```

Comment: Sorry Ashish, your solution `Took 7.47899985313 s` so I have to accept jpp which `Took 0.00399994850159 s`. Thanks nevertheless!